# Exporting products description (HTML) and short description (HTML)

Tags: magento-1.9, export, importexport

I need to export these 2 products columns: description (HTML) and short description (HTML) to a CSV.

So far I've been using the dataflow profile system with a personal columns mapping but I cannot get those 2 columns (I'm using v1.9).

Please can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below custom script :

**Option 1** :

```
<?php
require './app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
$registry = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
$registry->register('isSecureArea', true);

//Store id of exported products, This is useful when we have multiple stores. 
$store_id = 1;

$fp = fopen("productdata.csv","w+");


/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection */
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
/** Apply filters here */
$collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->load();


foreach ($collection as $product)
{
    $data = array();
    $data[] = $product->getSku();
    $data[] = $product->getDescription();
    $data[] = $product->getShortDescription();

fputcsv($fp, $data);    
}
fclose($fp)
?>
```

Option 2 :

**Goto your phpmyadmin click 'database' than put below query than export output as CSV format**

```
select * from catalog_product_entity_text where attribute_id IN (75,76);
```

Comment: Thanks Dan for your answer, but there is another detail: my shop is a multishop/multidomain with five langs. So should I specify the language before, or in the export there will be all the languages? And then will the column description and short description contain html tags?